# Inheriting protected constructor

Tags: c++, using, constructor-inheritance

As far as I understood, the `using` keyword can be used for inheriting constructors of a base class. In this code I'm trying to reuse the constructors of `Base` while making them public. Compilers say `error : calling a protected constructor of class 'Base'`. What is it that I'm misunderstanding here?

```
struct Base
{
protected:
    Base() = default;

    Base(int, int) {}
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;

};

//...

Derived1 d2(4,2); // ERROR
```